# kohana 3.3 admin responsive template with bootstrap

Tags: templates, kohana, responsive, adminlte

I'm trying to use Kohana framework 3.3 with this template:

[AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview)

But I don't know how to

Comment: What in particular do you not know how to do?